# Git rebasing for a branch with multiple merge commits

Tags: git, github, gitlab-ci, versioning

I am trying to break an older commit into more commits. The branch is pretty big and has more merge commits along the way. A simplification:

```
HEAD

A---B---merge_commit---C---merge_commit---D
```

In the above case, I want to split D into two commits.

I am currently doing:

```
git rebase -i D --rebase-merges
git reset HEAD~
'split into the two commits'
git commit 1
git commit 2
git rebase --continue
```

The problem is that I am getting conflicts at the merge conflicts and I tried with strategies (`ours`, `theirs`) and even manually but I can't get the branch after the rebase is finished to look like the branch before the rebase (`git diff` shows differences)

Any ideas on how could I solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what about just checkout files that conflict ?

Comment: In your graph : is `D` a recent commit  (e.g : more recent than `A, B, C` and the merge commits ? or is it older (e.g : the right most `merge_commit` is on top of `D`, then comes `C`, then another `merge_commit`, then `B` and `A`) ?

Comment: The head is at A so D is the oldest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're only rewriting ancestry, `git filter-branch` is your friend.

```
# in a scratch clone:
git clone -ns . $(mktemp -d); cd $_

git checkout D
git reset --patch @^  # to remove the bits that go in the next commit
git commit --amend
git commit -a

# now that you've got the new commits you want in place of D,
git replace D @
git filter-branch -- $(git branch --contains D)
```

and from there you can force-push the rewritten refs or just redo it in your original repo once you're sure you like all the rewrites it did or didn't do.  This will run *much* faster than rebase.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure you need the exact same states than after the merge.
get the sha of the merge commit and checkout each conflict files

```
git checkout <COMMIT-SHA> <path/to/the/messed/up/file>
git add <path/to/the/messed/up/file>
```

then

```
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Well yes that could work but I would add an extra commit. I want to just split the commit and the rest should be the same.

Comment: I don't understand this allow to add commit, and fix the conflict on merge